# PKI Server/CA Subject,Issuer Relation

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, imap, pki

I'm having trouble connecting to a IMAP server using java and keep geeting:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:298)
```

Using openssl I looked at the certificats and I am confused about the Subject and Issuer parts.

CA-Certificate from the Java certifacte store:

```
    Issuer: DC=at, DC=XXX, DC=intern, CN=intern-SERVER14-CA
    Validity
        Not Before: Nov 19 13:37:52 2014 GMT
        Not After : Nov 18 13:37:52 2016 GMT
    Subject: C=AT, ST=Vlbg, L=XXX, O=XXX, OU=XXX, CN=outlook.XXX.at
```

Certifcate obtained from the IMAP server using openssl:

```
Issuer: CN=server14
Validity
    Not Before: Oct 28 16:18:51 2014 GMT
    Not After : Oct 28 16:18:51 2019 GMT
Subject: CN=server14
```

Should not at least some of the Subject/Issuer parts match?

Trying `openssl verify` gives me `servercert.pem: /CN=server14
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate`

Comment: Rather than using the string-ified names in the Subject and Issuer, use the Authority Key Identifier (Issuer's signing key) and Subject Public Key Identifier (subject's public key). The key identifiers use the same relationship. The chain should terminate at a Root. Ideally, the root will be self signed, have `CA=true`, marked as critical, etc.